# Two model in core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I have two models on one page but only one at a time
They are sent to the server. The problem is that each of the models that I validate because the other model is empty, the binder model returns the wrong value. How can I tell the binder model to check only one model?

Comment: It seems that you should rethink your design because your page is responsible for more than one thing. You should also provide some code to illustrate your issue. Without more information, it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Do you have any custom validation or not?And how are you two models like?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ModelState.Remove("KeyName")` to ignore validating the model.But be sure there is **no client side validation js**( i.e. `jquery.validate.js` or `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`),otherwise,you will never get into the backend.

Here is a sample:

Model:

```
public class Userdata
{
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Test Test { get; set; }
}
public class Test
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
}
```

Backend code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    ModelState.Remove("UserData.Test");
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }
    return Page();
}
```